# Присвоить модели angular.js(javascript) переменную PHP

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Здравствуйте, снова появился вопрос имеем код

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.country = [{
    'name': 'Russia',
    'desc': 'Россия'
  }, {
    'name': 'Japan',
    'desc': 'Япония'
  }, {
    'name': 'China',
    'desc': 'Китай'
  }, {
    'name': 'USA',
    'desc': 'США'
  }];
});

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <input ng-model="query">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in country | filter:query">
      <label>
        <input name="qwer[]" type="checkbox" 
               ng-model="item.selected">{{item.desc}}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<input type="submit">                                
</form>
<?php
print_r($_POST['qwer']);
?>
```

Все сохраняем в переменную $_POST['qwer'], как заполнить модель при отправке пост запроса. (То  есть есть форма мы нажали кнопку отправить(пост запрос) данные из нашего checkbox убрались, нужно сделать чтобы те галочки которые были остались(вот тут и встал вопрос как обратно заполнить модель angular данными из пост переменной(Заранее благодарен))

Попробывал сделать как вы сказали не получается( пишет item.name(просто имя обращения)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет никакого смысла работать по модели "перезагрузка страницы на каждый чих" и одновременно использовать angular. Вам куда лучше подошел бы любой серверный шаблонизатор. Angular же больше дружит с технологией AJAX.

Впрочем, то, что вы хотите сделать, достигается несложно. Всего-то надо сформировать массив `country` сначала на сервере - а уже потом записывать. Как-то так:

```
<?php 
$country = array(
    array( name => 'Russia', desc => 'Россия', selected => true ),
    array( name => 'Japan', desc => 'Япония', selected => false ),
    array( name => 'China', desc => 'Китай', selected => true ),
    array( name => 'USA', desc => 'США', selected => false ))
// Разумеется, а реальном коде свойства selected вы будете заполнять исходя из $_POST
?>

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.country = <?php echo json_encode($country) ?>
});
```

Comment: Попробовал вставить как вы(имена name,desc в кавычки обрамил) {{item.desc}} пишет при выводе(я подозреваю, что просто передает нулевой массив в Js).

Comment: Попробовал задать в параметры (без массива в js) параметр selected не работает(

Comment: Если он вообще не отрабатывает, то, похоже, ангуляр ломается еще на полпути. Посмотрите, что за ошибки в консоли.

Comment: Дело не в этом, перепишем к примеру вот так<input name="qwer[]" type="checkbox" 
               ng-model="item.selected" checked>{{item.desc}} по идеи должны все ячейки выделнными стать.., но нет

Comment: Вроде бы решил проблему, сейчас доделаю и скину